# Indents in scientific articles (ACM)

Tags: indentation

I am completely new to TeX and would like to create a document building on the [ACM Guidelines](http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/proceedings-templates). Papers I've seen using these guidelines such as ["Driven by Food: Modeling Geographic Choice"](http://theory.stanford.edu/~sergei/papers/wsdm15-geochoice.pdf) have a small indent when they want to mark a new part of the paragraph. In Word I would create this indent using `Tab`. How do I do that in TeX? I would like to do it using some sort of "correct" indent width that all articles following the guidelines use.

Comment: This is, unless I'm woefully mistaken, actually the default LaTeX behaviour?? Have you, perhaps, got a template that loads `\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}` or something like that?

Comment: The ACM document class should come with documentation for any non-standard macros.  Also check out the quoting package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the paper you cite uses the "alternate" guidelines.
(the other format leaves space between paragraphs, and sets the first line
of the new paragraph flush left.)

to indicate a paragraph break, all you need to do is leave a blank line
before starting a new paragraph, or enter the command `\par`.
i usually recommend the blank line, because it makes the input file
easier to navigate visually.

the indentation will be inserted automatically.

Comment: Thank you, I completely missed that. Based on the text in the call for papers I would assume that both styles were usable ("Papers must be formatted according to ACM guidelines and style files to fit within 10 pages, including references, diagrams, and appendices if any. A submitted paper must be self-contained and in English."). However, I've only seen examples of the stricter style. Is there some sort of unformal norm about using the stricter styler with the permission/copyright? I'm also curious as to why the "normal" guidelines omit the permission block and copyright line.

Comment: @felbo -- not being an acm author, i'm afraid i can't give any useful answer regarding acm preferences.  (all i can claim, since i do write documentation and answer questions for ams authors, is that i've learned to read and interpret the documentation provided by other publishers.)